# Iptables commands causes crash and hangs the root account

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vpn, strongswan

I'm setting up a StrongSwan VPN server on an Amazon Ubuntu Server (16.04LTS) instance. I am using [this guide](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_vpn_with_Ubuntu_16.04.html).

I've completed almost all of the steps, I'm now trying to create `iptables` rules to allow traffic to the VPN server.

However, when I run this command:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source [machine's external ip] -o eth+`
the server seems to hang. After ~30 seconds I get the following message:
`packet_write_wait: Connection to [machine's external ip] port 22: Broken pipe`

I can log in again to the server under the `ubuntu` account, but once I use `sudo -i` or `sudo su`, the connection hangs again.

I'm probably doing something wrong with this command, causing a feedback loop of some kind, but I can't figure out what to do instead. Is the guide wrong, and should it be something else than the `machine's external ip`?

If any more info is needed, please ask!

Comment: Looks like a comms issue connecting to the external IP. Can you ping, telnet to the port etc?

Comment: Could you detail how you are connecting to the server in the question?

Comment: I can still ping the server, and login to the `ubuntu` account, but I can't `sudo su` into `root` anymore. I'm connecting over SSH with a private key.